# App installed on device but doesent show up

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest

#### Hi,Im new to android development and wrote a simple code to run a simple application.But when i run it on the emulator or on my device,the console window says that the app has successfully installed but nothing opens up on my emulator or phone.can u plz suggest a possible way of solving this problem.

## Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.firstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".First"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_first" >
    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

## activity_main

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" >

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberPassword" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="Enter your Password"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

    <requestFocus android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

   </EditText>

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="Enter your E-mail id"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:src="@drawable/robo" 
    android:contentDescription="@null"/>

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="Welcome To Foodparkk"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add your intent-filter to your activity not in manifest tag :

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main">

 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: Thanx for replying,I did that but still same thing is happening

Comment: @Shashwat : did you remove the intent-filter from manifest tag?

Comment: @Arash-ya I did that,but still the problem remains the same,ive edited the above code to show what I've witten in manifest and activity_main

Comment: @Shashwat : why you add intent-filter to your layout file , just do what i said , inside your manifest file add intent-filter to your activity tag.

Comment: @Arash-Thanx a lot,it worked,is their any other way i can get in touch with u to learn more from you.?

Comment: @Shashwat : ty for accepting , here in stackoverflow you can definitely find your issues with help of other programmers if you define your problem clearly but you can see my Linkedin profile inside my profile page